# RDLC Report Issue There is a issue in my report when i open report first time it open correctly when i open another report it gives errors

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, reporting, rdlc

[image: 1]

There is a issue in my report when i open report first time it open correctly when i open another report it give me parameters #Error sometimes checkboxes errors or somtimes my report is not load or give error IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It would be great if you could share your code snippet instead of screenshot. 
Post the code and error as text, not images. Images can't be copied, googled or tested.